# Ошибка при создании датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

При попытке создания датафрейма

```
temp_date = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1'], dtype=np.datetime64)
```

появляется ошибка:

> ValueError: Cannot convert from specific units to generic units in NumPy datetimes or timedeltas

Установлена python 3.8.0 , подключены numpy 1.22.1, pandas 1.4.0
Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего это может происходить?

Comment: Вы поленились поискать ответ самостоятельно? нужно указывать помимо типа еще и единица измерения времени. `temp_date = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1'], dtype="datetime64[s]")`

Comment: Вам уже ответил уважаемый @strawdog как это правильно сделать, но у вас изначально неправильный подход. Лучше создавать DataFrame когда у вас уже есть данные (например список записей в виде списка списков). Советую привести в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Тогда вы сможете получить квалифицированный и проверенный ответ.

Comment: @strawdog подскажите пожалуйста, в чем разница? Код, который я сейчас пытаюсь запустить, не мой. С помощью него мне нужно загрузить данные из cvs файла в influx. У автора он работает. У меня почему-то нет. Никак не модифицировала.

Comment: Я не знаю, какой именно код у автора, вероятно он все-таки создаёт не пустой датафрейм, а получает его из готового массива. Если так, то numpy  способен попытаться сам определить единицы времени на основании исходных данных, из-за чего у автора кода данная ошибка не появляется. Либо (возможно) у него  какая-то старая версия модуля.